# How can I make an element on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

All I'm trying to do is something like this mechanism:

[image]

Here is what I've tried so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
      var self = $(this);
      this.iid = setInterval(function() {
        var tag_name = self.text(),
             top      = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
             left     = self.position().left;
         self.append("<div class='tag_info'>Some explanations about"+tag_name+"</div>")
         $(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", left: left + "px"}).fadeIn(200);   
      }, 525);
  }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
     this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  padding: 20px;
}

a {
    color: #3e6d8e !important;
    background-color: #E1ECF4;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
.tag_info{
  position: reletive;
  width: 130px;
  height: 30px;
  display:none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>tag1</a>
<a>tag2</a>
```

As you see, it will be repeated every time. How can I execute it once per hover? And why the position doesn't apply?

Also is what I'm doing a right algorithm for such thing?

Thank you.

Comment: LOL - That is a really bad example to use as a screen shot this time of night. I thought one of the category's had a permanent hover over the text of your question.

Comment: @Difster ahaha yeah me too when I see the question `:-)`

Comment: Why aren't you just using this?
$('a').hover(function(){
//tool tip code
});

Comment: I don't think you need a set Interval to show that hover popup. fade in do the same behavior of interval and instead of clear interval use fade out

Comment: @JEMI Well I need it. I want a delay for showing that pop up. It's an ajax request in reality. So I don't want to send an request per every hover. I want to do that for long time hovered `:-)`

Comment: then I would suggest write a callback function for set interval to open up the popup

Comment: As an alternative, you can keep a hidden div at the body level, and keep on reusing it for tooltip needs. Should be slightly more performant than Dom insertions on all the frequent mouse interactions.

Comment: @hazardous Sounds good.

Comment: set interval and ajax are different behaviors.setInterval calls that function to show popup everytime when reach the interval. Ajax will calls once.

Comment: @JEMI I know, that ajax request is into interval.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using setInterval but I think this should work. I removed setInterval and everytime the mouseenter event occurs we can append `<div class='tag_info'>` and every time mouseleave event occurs we can remove the the appended div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').bind('mouseenter', function() {
      var self = $(this);
        var tag_name = self.text(),
             top      = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
             left     = self.position().left;
         self.append("<div class='tag_info'>Some explanations about"+tag_name+"</div>")
         $(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", left: left + "px"}).fadeIn(200);   
  }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
     $(this).children('.tag_info').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  padding: 20px;
}

a {
    color: #3e6d8e !important;
    background-color: #E1ECF4;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
.tag_info{
  position: reletive;
  width: 130px;
  height: 30px;
  display:none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test">tag1</a>
```

Comment: Your code isn't what I wanted. Because it will show that pop up immediately. It's an ajax request in reality. So I don't want to send an request per every hover quickly, I need a delay. I mean I want to do that for long time hovered

Comment: @stack then won't it be a better option to use setTimeout and clear the timeout on mouseleave, since timeout executes only once.

Answer (score 1):

Like Dij said:

- What you're doing:

  - setInterval - (repeats your function every 525ms)
- What you want:

  - setTimeout - (executes your function once after 525ms delay)

**Read more:**

setInterval https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

setTimeout https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp